# Python : nested iteritems loop only run once

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to loop over a dictionary, and append dictionary inside it. But when I use loop using iteritems(), it just iterating once and exit to the outer loop. I am quite new in python but I think this code should be working.

Why this happen?

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import pprint

training = {"outlook":{"sunny":{"yes":2,"no":3},"overcast":{"yes":4,"no":0},"rainy":{"yes":3,"no":2}},\
            "temperature":{"yes":[83,70,68,64,69,75,75,72,81],"no":[85,80,65,72,71]},\
            "humidity":{"yes":[86,96,80,65,70,80,70,90,75],"no":[85,90,70,95,91]},\
            "windy":{"false":{"yes":6,"no":2},"true":{"yes":3,"no":3}},\
            "play":{"yes":9,"no":5}}
processed = {}
total_yes = training["play"]["yes"]
total_no = training["play"]["no"]
total_all = training["play"]["no"]+training["play"]["yes"]

def main():
    for k,v in training.iteritems():
        if(k != "play"):
            for k2,v2 in v.iteritems():
                if((k2 == "yes") & isinstance(v2,list)):
                    processed[k] = {"yes":{"mean":numpy.mean(v2),"std":numpy.std(v2,ddof=1)}}
                elif((k2 == "no") & isinstance(v2,list)):
                    processed[k].update({"no":{"mean":numpy.mean(v2),"std":numpy.std(v2,ddof=1)}})
                else:
                    processed[k] = {}

                    # the problems start here
                    for i,j in v2.iteritems():
                        if(i == "yes"):
                            p_yes = j/total_yes
                            processed[k].update({k2:{"yes":p_yes,"no":(1-p_yes)}})
                        #when I print processed[k], it contains current value only (not including previous value)
                #suddenly exit after iterating once

        else:
            processed[k] = {"yes":total_yes/total_all,"no":total_no/total_all}

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=3)
    pp.pprint(processed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is :

```
...
'outlook': {  'sunny': {  'no': 0.7777777777777778,
                          'yes': 0.2222222222222222}},
...
```

But expected output is :

```
...
'outlook': {  'sunny': {  'no': 0.7777777777777778,
                          'yes': 0.2222222222222222}},
              'overcast': { 'no':xxxxx,
                            'yes':xxx
                          }
              ...
...
```

Comment: I use 2.7 @BillBEGUERADJ

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind which you want to insert an other dictionary inside the first one?

Comment: basically I want to iterate each deepest value in the the "outlook" key, calculate its probability, and push it back into "processed" variable. I'm doing this to keep the structure same as original @BillBEGUERADJ

Comment: Why are you printing 'properties'?

Comment: sorry, it just mistype @LiorMagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistake was that you always erase the 'outlook' and in the end you see the last entry that was inserted into 'outlook' dictionary. Here is a fix of your code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import pprint

training = {"outlook":{"sunny":{"yes":2,"no":3},"overcast":{"yes":4,"no":0},"rainy":{"yes":3,"no":2}},\
        "temperature":{"yes":[83,70,68,64,69,75,75,72,81],"no":[85,80,65,72,71]},\
        "humidity":{"yes":[86,96,80,65,70,80,70,90,75],"no":[85,90,70,95,91]},\
        "windy":{"false":{"yes":6,"no":2},"true":{"yes":3,"no":3}},\
        "play":{"yes":9,"no":5}}
processed = {}
total_yes = training["play"]["yes"]
total_no = training["play"]["no"]
total_all = training["play"]["no"]+training["play"]["yes"]


def main():
    for k,v in training.iteritems():
        if (k=='outlook'):
            pass
        if(k != "play"):
            for k2,v2 in v.iteritems():
                if((k2 == "yes") & isinstance(v2,list)):
                    processed[k] = {"yes":{"mean":numpy.mean(v2),"std":numpy.std(v2,ddof=1)}}
                elif((k2 == "no") & isinstance(v2,list)):
                    processed[k].update({"no":{"mean":numpy.mean(v2),"std":numpy.std(v2,ddof=1)}})
                else:
                    if k not in processed:
                        processed[k] = {}

                    for i,j in v2.iteritems():
                        if(i == "yes"):
                            p_yes = j/total_yes
                            processed[k].update({k2:{"yes":p_yes,"no":(1-p_yes)}})                       


        else:
            processed[k] = {"yes":total_yes/total_all,"no":total_no/total_all}

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=3)
    pp.pprint(processed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
else:
    processed[k] = {}
```

The previous value of k is overwritten as your for loop moves to the next element.

Define this here and your problem should be solved:

```
for k,v in training.iteritems():
    if(k != "play"):
        processed[k] = {}
```